# TestCafe: User Roles - ERROR The specified glob pattern does not match any file or the default test directories are empty

Tags: automated-tests, roles, e2e-testing, testcafe, web-testing

I am trying to use Use Role in TC according to the https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/authentication/user-roles.html

In my opinion, everything is ok but I receive an 
ERROR The specified glob pattern does not match any file or the default test directories are empty.

I do not understand why. Could somebody point where is the mistake?

```
> import { ClientFunction } from 'testcafe'; 
> // take url import config from './Config/config'; 
> import loginPage from './POM_LoginPage';
> import Elements from './POM_Elements'; 
>import {Role} from 'testcafe'
> 
> 
> let l1 =  require('./support/global').log[1];
> 
> const SuperUser = Role(`${config.baseUrl}`, async t => {
>     //Log in as superuser
> 
>   await loginPage.logIn(l1.username, l1.password)
> 
> });
> 
> ixture`SanityTests`  
>   .beforeEach(async t => {
>     await t.maximizeWindow()   })  
>   .page`${config.baseUrl}`;
> 
> 
>   test('Navigation to the Users components', async t => {
> 
>     //Log in
>    
>     await t.useRole(SuperUser);
> 
>     //Go to the "other page"
> 
>     await t.click(Elements.navDropdown);
>     await t.click(Elements.usersButton);
> 
>    const users= ClientFunction(() => window.location.href) 
>    await
>    t.expect(users()).contains(`${config.Url}`);
>       })
```

Comment: Try single quoting the glob on the cli arguments / config file.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is not related to the [Roles](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/authentication/user-roles.html) feature. The error message tell about that you specifying a wrong glob path pattern for the executed tests. Check that the specified path value match any tests.
For more information see the [Runner.src](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/configuration-file.html#src) method description.